# Wildcard SSL from Letsencrypt - Ok, but CN still “domain.com” not “*.domain.com”

Tags: ssl, wildcard, virtualmin

SYSTEM INFORMATION
OS type and version CentOS Linux 7.5.1804
Webmin version  [1.998]
Virtualmin version  [7.1]
I installed a wildcard ssl certificate from Letsencrypt but in the browser when verifying the certificate it shows CN = “domain.com” not “*.domain.com”.
What do I need to do, what settings to enter in order to display the correct wildcard certificate?
Thanks!

Comment: The CN is irrelevant. Subject Alternative Names (SAN) are used instead, i.e. check these instead.

Comment: Subject Alternative Names (SAN) = DNS-name=*.domain.com DNS-name=domain.com
But if I activate vpn in opera browser, I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR and the subdomain doesn't open. Main domain opens without errors

Comment: Does it work without VPN?

Comment: Yes. But I know another domain, behind Cloudflare, with wildcard ssl letsencrypt, and it works good with opera VPN... and it CN = *.domain.com

Comment: I think you need to provide the specific domain name so one can see what is exactly going on.

Comment: https://2much.info/
https://bauhaus.2much.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is not properly configured. TLS works with IPv4 for both 2much.info and bauhaus.2much.info. For IPv6 though there is no address with 2much.info but there is one for bauhaus.2much.info. Only, TLS is not enabled here, it returns instead plain HTTP on port 443.

IPv6 capable clients will usually prefer IPv6 to IPv4. The attempt of using Opera without VPN might be done in a IPv4 environment, so the working IPv4 address is used. When using the VPN though other systems will access the  target and these might be IPv6 enabled - in which case the access fails.

This can also be seen in a IPv6 capable environment. It is working with IPv4:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect bauhaus.2much.info:443 -4
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

But failing with IPv6

```
$ openssl s_client -connect bauhaus.2much.info:443 -6
CONNECTED(00000003)
140692571469632:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```